# Lazy evaluation of apply function implemented with variate template in C++

Tags: c++, templates, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to write my own apply function using variate template. Here is the code I have:

```
    template<typename...>
    struct types{
    };

    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    struct Func{
        template<typename F, typanem... Types>
        T call(F f, std::tuple<Types...>& params, Args... args){
            return _call(f, params, types<Types...>{}, args...);
        }
        template<typename F, typename Tuple, typename Head, typename... Tail, typename... Args>
        T _call(F f, Tuple& t, types<Head, Tail...>, Args&&... args){
            _call(f, t, types<Tail...>{}, std::forward<Args>(args)..., std::get<sizeof...(Arg)>(t).DrawSample()));
        }
        T _call(F f, Tuple& t, types<>, Args... vs){ 
            return f(vs...)
        }
    };
```

I can compile and run the above code without any difficulty. Now I want to make the function call(...) being invoked lazily. In other words, I can first construct the function by passing in all parameters needed for the computation:

```
    int getMax(float f1, float f2, float f3){
      if(f1 >= f2 && f1 >= f3){
          return 1;
      }
      if(f2 >= f1 && f2 >= f3){
          return 2;
      }
      if(f3 >= f1 && f3 >= f2){
          return 3;
      }
    }
    Func<int> func;
    //Gaussian(mu, sd) is an object which can generate random values based on Gaussian 
    //distribution described with mu(mean) and sd(standard deviation).
    Gaussian *g1 = Gaussian(0.3, 0.2);
    Gaussian *g2 = Gaussian(0.2, 0.3);
    Gaussian *g3 = Gaussian(0.3, 0.3);
    func.setCall(getMax, std::make_tuple(*g1, *g2, *g3);
    cout<<func.DrawSample();
```

After constructing the function, I hope to get the result of the getMax() function lazily each time I make a query for func.DrawSample(). Under the hood, perhaps DrawSample() calls call(...). However, is there anyway for me to change the code above in order to create a setCall(...) whose purpose is to store everything needed for later function calls?

Please let me know if my question is still unclear. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Do you want to call `Gaussian::operator()` each time you call `getMax()`?

Comment: Could you tell us why `auto func = bind(getMax, Gaussian(0.3, 0.2), Gaussian(0.2, 0.3), Gaussian(0.3, 0.3));` can't be used instead?

Comment: Kind of. In my Gaussian implementation, I define a DrawSample() function which pulls out a float each time.

Comment: getMax has declaration getMax(float, float, float), while Gaussian is an object instead of a float.

Comment: Are you suggesting to define a operator inside Gaussian instead of DrawSample() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
template<class Func, class... Args>
    int applyDrawSample(Func func, Args... args)
{
    return func(args.DrawSample()...);
}

template<class Func, class... Args>
    auto bind_helper(Func func, Args... args)
    -> decltype(bind(applyDrawSample<Func, Args...>, func, args...))
{
    return bind(applyDrawSample<Func, Args...>, func, args...);
}
```

Usage:

```
auto func = bind_helper(getMax, Gaussian(...), Gaussian(...), Gaussian(...));

func();
```

A trivial extra lambda can change the last call to look like `func->DrawSample()`, if you really want it, and is left as an exercise.

## EDIT

If you need a type for `func` above, it can be `std::function`:

```
function<int()> func = bind_helper(...);
```

The function signature (in this case, a function with no arguments, returning an `int`) for `std::function` needs to be compatible with what you are assigning.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. It is really helpful. The suggestion makes the implementation much cleaner! I'm not quite good at lambda. Therefore, I still have a follow up question. I can put the two functions into my class definition. However, is there any way that I can store the return value of bind_helper somehow as a member so that later I can invoke it again and again?

Comment: To make the question clearer, is there any way that I can save func as a member field of a class? Or can I do it in some other way, like the extra lambda mentioned in your answer? I don't know how to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::function<int()>` and lambdas.

```
std::function<int()> func;
func = [=]()->int {
  return getMax( Guassian(0.3,0.2), Guassian(0.2,0.3), Guassian(0.3,0.3) );
};
std::cout << func();
```

If you really, really need your interface, simply store a `std::function<T()>` within your `class`, and the `setCall` simply assigns to it.

But really, your object is some anonymous type that can be invoked to produce an `int` -- `std::function` solves the problem.  You'll have to engage in type erasure anyhow, as the type of your class does not include the function signature, so you probably won't be any more efficient.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I do need the interface, because I cannot expect what kind of functions can be passed in as parameters for Func. In this example, it is getMax, but it definitely can be something else. I think getMax(Gaussian(...), Gaussian..., Gaussian...) is not a valid statement, since getMax()'s declarations require all input parameters should be float instead of Gaussian

Answer (score 0):

With the suggestion provided by DanielKO, I finally come up with a solution for my specific scenario.
Here is the final version of my compiled code.

```
    template<class Func, class... Args>
    int applyDrawSample(Func func, Args&&... args){
        return func((*args).DrawSample()...);
    }
    template<class Func, class... Args>
    auto bind_helper(Func func, Args&&... args) ->decltype(bind(applyDrawSample<Func, Args...>,  
        func, args...))
    {
        return bind(applyDrawSample<Func, Args...>, func, args...);
    }

    template<typename T>
    struct UncertainFunc{
        template<typename F, typename... Args>
        void setFunc(F f, Args... args){
            function = bind_helper(f, args...);
        }
        T DrawSample(){
            return function();
        }
        std::function<T()> function;
    };

    UncertainFunc<int> ufunc;
    ufunc.setFunc(getMax, &(Gaussian(0.3, 0.2), &Gaussian(0.2, 0.3), &Gaussian(0.2, 0.2));
    ufunc.DrawSample();
```

Especially, it seems that I cannot put the bind_helper(...) function into my class definition for some reason (perhaps auto type?).